# Hyperlinks in bot using node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD8vq.png)  I am trying to use Bing search API to display news. But, I want it to be printed as hyperlinks, but I am not able to do it. The language I am using is Node.js.

```
.matches('Looking', function(session,args){

var StoreResponse = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities,'search');

StoreResponse = StoreResponse.entity          
    console.log(StoreResponse)

     console.log(StoreResponse)

      console.log(StoreResponse)

       console.log(StoreResponse)

  Bing.news(StoreResponse, {
    count: 10, 
    offset: 3   
  }, function(error, res, body){

    console.log(body.value[2].url);
    session.send(' \%s\  \n\n  \%s\ ',body.value[2].name,body.value[2].url)
    console.log(body.value[3].url);
     session.send(' \%s\  \n\n  \%s\ ',body.value[3].name,body.value[3].url)
    console.log(body.value[4].url);
     session.send(' \%s\  \n\n  \%s\ ',body.value[4].name,body.value[4].url)
    console.log(body.value[5].url);
     session.send(' \%s\  \n\n  \%s\ ',body.value[5].name,body.value[5].url)
    console.log(body.value[6].url);
     session.send(' \%s\  \n\n  \%s\ ',body.value[6].name,body.value[6].url)
  });

})
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem and what you tried.

Comment: So, I am trying to send news headlines and links as bot response, but I want only the headline to be displayed as a hyperlink so that user can click on it and access the news on the browser. But, I can'y figure out how to make the bot send hyperlinks to the user.

Comment: You can use a hero card, which has option to provide URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ronak mentioned, you can try to leverage Hero Card in Botframework. Please try following code snippet:

```
const card = new builder.HeroCard(session);
card.title("Title");
// card.subtitle("Subtitle");
card.images([builder.CardImage.create(session,"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/media/hubs/botframework/bot-framework-intelligence-smarter.svg")])

card.text("<a href='https://bing.com'>Bing</a>");
const msg = new builder.Message(session);
msg.textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml);
msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
msg.attachments([
    card
]).toMessage();
session.endDialog(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the Markdowns available. Bot Framework converts Markdown to the rich native formats for each channel. But they are not supported in all the channels.

This is the [list](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2016/08/22/bot-framework-markdown-support-by-channel/) to all the markdowns available. For sending links as a hyperlink you can use this markdown `[YOUR-TEXT](THE-LINK)`.

So for your result from Bing news you could try something like this:

```
var msg = '[${body.value[2].name}](${body.value[2].url})';
session.send(msg);
```